# PHP - RPS - 'Multiplayer' rock, paper, scissors mini game - How to store and pass variables?

Tags: php, variables

I have made the structure of the game (I can play it vs the bot), but I want to make it a player vs player game. How do I store and pass variables then? Should I store it in my database (one table for game id, one for 'move' id) or is there a simpler way? I do not intent to keep a score count or store anything for the next time the same player want's to play again.

Here is the code I have so far (the player vs bot/ structure of the game. This does not include the form and the other HTML on the page):

```
$X = $_POST['X'];
$Y = rand(1, 3);
$A = $X-$Y+3;
$R = fmod($A, 3);

if ($R == 0) {
    echo 'draw!';
} elseif ($R == 1) {
    echo 'you won!';
} elseif ($R == 2) {
    echo 'you lost!';
} else {
    echo 'an error occurred!';
}
```

If you want to see the full script, please let me know.

My idea of the database and the tables:

```
Table: Users

UserID    Username    (I don't include email, password and salt here...)
1         Espen
2         Test

Table: Games

GameID    Participant1 Participant2 Winner
1         1            2            1
1         1            2            2

Table: Moves

MoveID    GameID       UserID       Move
1         1            1            2
2         1            2            1
3         2            1            3
4         2            2            1
```

Values of moves: 1-rock, 2-paper, 3-scissors

Thanks in advance!

-Espen

Comment: 2 players in the same pc? First, the player 1 input, when he submit, asks for player 2 input.. and then, show the result? You can use input hidden for store the POST value of player one ;)

Comment: I would like it to be on different computers on different networks. The script is on my web server. Is that going to be hard and complicated?

Comment: No... but, how do you know against who are playing? What happen if 3 users open the web?

Comment: I do have a authentication system (simple, and I am not sure if it is very safe or not. It uses Sha256+SLAT on the password, it is session based. I did not make it myself, it was a tutorial/done script). I thought of having a new entry in a table 'games' (to store the game id and the winner) and then a table 'moves' (to store the different moves by the individual users). I can try to illustrate what I mean in my answer.

Comment: By saying I have the authentication system, I meant I can identify the users that way (must be logged in to play).